# Extract Date Format using powershell

Tags: powershell, ssl

Hello I have a powershell script that shows me the expiration date of a certificate ssl using this format

> notAfter=Aug 17 22:00:00 2015 GMT

I want to extract only the date (remove `notAfter=` and `GMT`) and to assure that I have a Date format variable and not a string, then I want to extract that value from current date and get the difference, I tried remove and replace and both changed nothing.
To be more precise this is the command that gives me the `notafter` value

`$timessl = ((& openssl x509 -in /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.pem -dates -noout) -match 'notAfter')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$timessl="notAfter=Aug 17 22:00:00 2015 GMT"
$t=$timessl.Replace("notAfter=","").Replace("GMT","")
write-output $t
```